How do I complete Test Chamber 8 in Single-Player on Portal 2?
I've been stuck on this Test Chamber for a while now and I don't know how to complete it.
What I've done so far:

Pressed the button to get a cube
Put the cube in the laser to point the laser to the circle in the wall


You would think that this is all that is required to open the door, but no. The door doesn't open:

I don't know what else to do. How can I complete Test Chamber 8?

Oops. I just figured it out. Stupid mistake on my end.
I was looking at the wrong door. Opposite the door I was looking at is another door:

And this is the correct door that I should go to. I thought this was the door I came from since it was open and the other one was closed.
So yeah. What I did was correct.
Simply press the button, get the cube, and point the cube in the laser to the circle in the wall, and then the door opens and you can finish the Test Chamber.

The game is actually guiding you really well here. The dotted line going from the Circle that needs a laser to the door is there to indicate, that this is what opened the door and the walking person sign indicates this is the door to walk through.

@TreeSpawned I had not noticed that until this mission

The large light-up signs are also generally found next to entrance doors, rather than exits.
